# How to update rights if role changed while logged in?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a WPF desktop app.
It is a usermanagement software with different user roles and rights.
If I'm logging in I call a method to display only the buttons of the users role.
But if the role of the user is changed (from another user), how can I notify the programm instance of this user to call the method again to update his rights?

I tried to create a thread to call the method every 10 seconds, but it wasn't working because it was using by another thread?!
Anyways this is not the way to call a method every 10 seconds.
Is there any better option?

Comment: Please add more details. You state that you call method to get user rights - is is database query or REST call or something different? What is your architecture? Do you develop only desktop app which uses some other service, or you do both?

Comment: On login I request the user and its roles from the database and store it to variable (I use EF 6.0). Then I check the buttons against the role level of the user with the required level for the button (this is the method I was talking about). I only develop a desktop app at the moment.